# Is there any direct method to fetch data from a Couchbase server to R Studio?

Tags: rstudio, couchbase

I'm fairly new to this issue with virtually no experience with Couchbase, so i might just overlooked some easy and direct way to access data contained in it to R Studio. Do you guys know about a solution?

Do i have to process such queries through some other platforms?

Any tips or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchdb has restful http interface so you can query the database directly using that. There is this package for R that should make it easier for you:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html

Here is an example of a Uri that might be used to query a couch view:

```
 /database/_design/designdocname/_view/viewname.
```

Bear in mind that couch is rather unusual in that getting getting data out of it requires views to be set up in the database. You may be unable to make certain queries without creating views in the admin interface.

But if you are just querying existing views, an http client is all you need.